# How to show all logs from VM in the Google Compute Engine Logging?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, logging

I have a simple VM instance running on Google Compute Engine. I am running a docker container in attached mode so everytime I send a request I can see logs coming from the container in the ssh-in-browser terminal, like `...GET / HTTP1.1 200 OK` etc.

What is the simplest way to enable showing those logs in the Google Logging? For now I can only see the logs from firewall (by default). But I cant find any way to see the logs coming directly from VM terminal that I can see when I connect to the VM.

I would want to see exact messages in google logging that I can see in the terminal for that VM.

Comment: 1) Are you looking in the right place: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/activity-logs 2) Did you install the logging agent: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logging-gce-quickstart#install-agent 3) Did you configure the logging agent: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/configuration

Comment: @JohnHanley so I managed to show the logs from Docker-compose in the logging by adding `log-driver: gcplogs` in the docker-compose file, however the issue is that with this approach I cant view the logs in the terminal anymore, only in logging tab in cloud console.

Comment: @ Alex T is your issue resolved, If yes If your issue is resolved ple post it. So, that it will be helpful for other community members